# Open File Description Locks confusion

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, locking, flock

As in - https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open-File-Description-Locks.html#Open-File-Description-Locks

`fcntl(F_OFD_SETLK)` locks on an open file table entry, (usually obtained by `open()`). Easy to understand.

But in the following example :

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open-File-Description-Locks-Example.html#Open-File-Description-Locks-Example.

In its example process, each thread calls `open()`, so each file descriptor should point to a different open file table entry.

Then doing `fcntl (fd, F_OFD_SETLKW, &lck)` in each thread is just getting a lock on a different open file table entry, which means this locking is completely wrong.

But I tested on Ubuntu, and it works for some reason. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post links, but instead include the references in your question.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko: The question already describes content of the links. While this is done with *rewording*, the meaning is clear (at least, for me). However, pasting the code from the docs would make the question better. (As the code is not long).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - that's exactly what I meant - code from links.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but: multiple file **descriptors** can point to the same open file **description**. In this case, the `OFD`-style calls set advisory locks on the description itself (and thus is non-portable as it is a Linux concept) rather than the descriptor. Subtle difference.